# convert scientific notation into a character

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame that should be a character with a pattern of *num, char, num, num* (ex: 1C72) but any observation with an E was written in scientific notation in the original csv. (ex: 8.00E+04)

Here's what I tried:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
example = as.data.frame(c("1B73","1C24","2.00E+08", "4.00E+04", "SBV123"))
colnames(example)[1] <- "x"
example$x = as.character(example$x)

#isolate problematic column  
setDT(example)[nchar(example$x) == 8, x8:=x]

#create new columns for data we want  
example$a <- substr(example$x8,1,1)
example$b <- substr(example$x8,5,5)
example$c <- substr(example$x8,7,8)
example$good <- paste(example$a,example$b,example$c,sep = "")
example$good[example$good == "NANANA"] <- NA

#combine good data:  
example = example %>% mutate(g2 = coalesce(good, x))
```

This solution works but is quite lengthy and creates a lot of columns. Is there any way to do this without creating a bunch of columns?

Desired Output:

```
|g2    |
|1B73  |
|1C24  |
|2E08  |
|4E04  |
|SBV123|
```

Comment: could you give the desired output? I don't think you need to load all those packages to achieve what you want...

Comment: maybe you could just gsub everything from . to + and only keep the E? gsub("\\..*(E).*\\+", "\\1", c("1B73","1C24","2.00E+08", "4.00E+04", "SBV123"))

Comment: Use formatC? `set.seed(1); x = runif(10, 0, 2)^runif(10,5,10); formatC(x, format = "E", digits=0)` then you can sub out the `+` if you really want to.

Comment: probably `gsub("(\\.00)|(\\+)", "", c("1B73","1C24","2.00E+08", "4.00E+04", "SBV123"))` will do. Though the best thing would be to make sure anything is well formatted in the csv...

Comment: Cath, this worked. Thank you